# Do pilots of modern high-end aircraft normally communicate their destination to ATC?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations, pre-clearance

Do pilots of modern high-end aircraft ever verbally communicate their destination to ATC? My understanding is clearance delivery is done electronically and when listening to ATC I haven't heard any instance where the pilot stated the destination to ATC (either on takeoff or en-route).

Comment: You have to listen to Clearance Delivery not Tower or Center

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [usa](/questions/tagged/usa), **yes, the destination airport is transmitted verbally over the radio** by many pilots at many airports.

As you say, at certain airports and for certain operators the IFR clearance may be issued non-verbally. In the USA there are two options: the *Pre-Departure Clearance* program (PDC) and the *Controller-Pilot Data Link Communications — Departure Clearance* program (CPDLC-DCL).

PDC clearances are issued by ATC "in the blind" without waiting for a request from the pilot,<sup>1</sup> and so the departure airport is never confirmed; it is incumbent on the pilot to read their issued clearance and verify that the clearance limit is correct. CPDLC-DCL clearances require that the pilot be "logged on" to the CPDLC  system, but once they are connected to that system, the clearance is again issued automatically without a specific request by the pilot.<sup>2</sup> When using CPDLC the pilot will confirm receipt of the clearance. In neither case will the destination airport be mentioned over a radio frequency.

**However**, if there is a problem with the clearance, or if either the ATC facility or the pilot does not have the equipment necessary to utilize PDC/CPDLC, the pilot will have to radio the Clearance Delivery controller and verbally request a clearance.

From the [Aeronautical Information Manual 5–2–6**h**2](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_2.html#%24paragraph5-2-6), when calling on the radio to copy their IFR clearance, the pilot is expected to:

> State the following information in the initial call‐up to the facility when no change has been made to the filed flight plan: Aircraft call sign, location, type operation (IFR) **and the name of the airport (or fix) to which you expect clearance.**

In my experience almost every pilot—Part 91, Part 135, and Part 121—will follow the above recommendation. They will verbally transmit their intended destination airport to the Clearance Delivery controller, despite the filed flight plan including that clearance limit already.

---

<sup>1</sup> AC 90-117 Table 2-1
<sup>2</sup> AC 90–117 2.10.3.2

Further reading:

[AIM 5–2–2 Automated Pre-Departure Clearance Procedures](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_2.html#%24paragraph5-2-2)
[Advisory Circular 90-117](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/90-117) (*thanks @ymb1*)
[ForeFlight: PDC FAQs](https://foreflight.com/support/pdc/)
[BoldMethod: Pre-Departure Clearance: What Is It?](https://www.boldmethod.com/blog/expressjet/pre-departure-clearance-what-is-it-and-how-do-you-get-one/)

Comment: PDC does require an action from the pilot. Either it is actively requested or - in case of the United States - it is sent after pilots log on to the ATC network (ie. make a "notification") before departure.

Comment: @busdriver: see my edited answer, which now specifies that it is correct for the USA only—I should have said that in the first place. PDC never requires a specific request from the pilot, and I clarified that CPDLC-DCL also does not require a *specific* request but does require the pilot to log on to the CPDLC system.

Comment: Nice answer,  but "*according to FAA-Regulations..."* - what regulation are you referring to?

Comment: Can you clarify whether your comment that most pilots will verbally transmit their intended destination applies to those using PDC/CPDLC? I have been listening to KAUS "clearance delivery" on liveatc and it seems virtually no one is requesting clearance over that channel.

Comment: @757toga, I am referring to the AIM specifically, which is (as we all know) not regulatory. But `tag:FAA` would not apply and IMO `tag:USA` would be too broad—though I am open to persuasion on that point.

Comment: @flopper: *when pilots call CD to copy a verbal clearance* they will state the destination airport. If you look at the airport diagram for AUS you will see that both PDC and CPDLC are available, so few if any of the airlines will call for a verbal clearance. If you instead listen to [EDC ground/clearance](https://www.liveatc.net/search/?icao=edc) on 119.45 you will likely hear some clearances being requested and issued. Check FlightAware to see when there might be a departing flight (they will call for clearance ~30-40 min prior to the time shown).

Comment: I suggest you just reference the AIM  and forego the FAA Regulation reference in your answer.  Also, you indicate that PDCs are issued in the *blind* and then it is *again* issued once the crew logs on to the network.  Can you clarify that?

Comment: @757toga: "again" is a rhetorical device emphasizing the similarities between PDC and CPDLC-DCL, which are separate systems; it does not imply that the same clearance is issued via both systems.

Answer (score 0):

The flight plan contains the desired route and destination.  Ot is communicated prior to the first radio call with clearance delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Communicate - yes ;
Verbally - mostly ;
Digitally - sometimes

As stated above, anything but a simple VFR-Flight will require a flightplan, which noch only states the destination and the route. This flightplan is mostly filed in written (or via computer) (though sometimes this can also be done via audio)

Next, the pilot will request a clearance, which states the destination again - this is normally done via voice-radio, though sometimes digitally transmissions is being used.

=> ATC is aware of your destination

Answer (score -1):

Every flight that intends to fly in controlled airspace needs to make a flight plan in advance that includes destination and intended route. In case of airlines, the flight plan is submitted by the dispatch office prior to flight.

Before departing, the flight needs a clearance that is merely a confirmation of the flight plan. In theory the clearance could include changes in filed route but that is rarely case in these days as any conflicts are in practice handled by the airline. In countries where the flight plan is required to include local departure procedures those are sometimes altered by the requirements of the departure airport.

The destination and route is confirmed (an thus communicated) when pilots request a route clearance. At major airports the clearance is issued usually by datalink so no verbal communication is required and even if voice procedures are used, the ATC already knows the destination of the flight as it is included in the flight plan.

Comment: I disagree that a clearance is "**merely** a confirmation of the flight plan." The clearance is the clearance and the flight plan is nothing but a plan. Just filing a flight plan is not sufficient to fly IFR in controlled airspace; the flight plan means nothing, the clearance means everything. And at least in the USA, ATC-issued reroutes are far from rare.

Comment: @randomhead: Those that fly long-haul to/from the coasts (international flights) rarely go through those *domestic* issues. // @ busdriver: please consider editing to clarify based on what (and where) conflicts are rare, it may help get your point across more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: Also a flight plan is not required for *every* flight in controlled airspace- consider a VFR flight.

Comment: -1 In Europe, if "modern high-end aircraft" are VFR then they don't need to file a flight plan to cross CAS (they do need a clearance).  Not sure about FAA-land but there's no location tag in the question.

Comment: *"Every flight that intends to fly in controlled airspace needs to make a flight plan in advance"*   HAH!  Tell that to my C-172.  I frequently take off without even knowing where I'm going, I can make it up along the way.

Comment: @DaveGremlin “Controlled Airspace” includes class E, which only requires a clearance if you’re IFR.

Comment: @StephenS   Oh yes, class E, I always forget about that, there's a bit near Belfast, and didn't Aberdeen get a wedge a few years back?  I've never been near class E so never been caught out. Mind, I don't need a clearance to cross a MATZ but I always 'request a penetration'. https://i1.wp.com/nats.aero/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/UKAirspaceClassifications.jpg